# Recursive function to calculate greatest common divisor

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to implement a recursive function to calculate the gcd of two numbers, but my code is not working, any idea what's wrong?

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return a;
    }

    while (a != b) {
        if (a > b) {
            gcd(a - b, b);
        } else if (b > a) {
            gcd(a, b - a);
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: In general, recursive strategies and `while` loops are mutually exclusive. Hope that helps as a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the while loop if you are using recursion. Just do:

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return a;
    }

    if (a > b)
        return gcd(a - b, b);

    return gcd(a, b - a);
}
```

By the way, `while (a != b)` is an infinite loop if it is reached.

Comment: Why is this an infinite loop? Don't the parameters a and b change when you call the function again?

Comment: @Maxim when do you expect a and b to change? You never change the values of a and b. They are primitive data types, they are not objects. When you call the function again with a smaller value of a or b, their values don't change in the current stack of the function.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Maxim glad it helped:)